# How to resolve a promise that sent to Subject parameters in Rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I pass a `Promise` to `Subject` as parameter:

```
const work = new Subject<{ id: number; dialogRef: Promise<typeof Dialog> }>();
```

And I want to use the instance inside the `promise` later:

```
...
exhaustMap(({ id, dialogRef }) =>
  http.get({ id }).pipe(tap(() => dialogRef.close()))
)
...
```

But the problem is `dialogRef` is a `Promise`, I need to resolve it before I use instance function (`close()`).

The one way I was be able to do that is using `async await`, but this solution is not good for me. because I want to do it using "rxjs" way.

I looking for operator or function that can resolve this promise and pass it to `exhaustMap` operator. something like that:

```
 resolve(({ dialogRef }) => dialogRef),
 exhaustMap(({ id, dialogRef }) => //<-- dialogRef is NOT promise. it's instance
      http.get({ id }).pipe(tap(() => dialogRef.close()))
 )
```

Can I do it with rxjs?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bvr7cc?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

```
import { of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
console.clear();

const http = {
  get: ({ id }) => of(`data: ${id}`),
};

const Dialog = {
  close: () => {
    console.log('in close!');
  },
};

const work = new Subject<{ id: number; dialogRef: Promise<typeof Dialog> }>();

work
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(({ id, dialogRef }) =>
      http.get({ id }).pipe(tap(async () => (await dialogRef).close()))
    )
  )
  .subscribe((r) => {
    console.log({ r });
  });

work.next({ id: 1, dialogRef: Promise.resolve(Dialog) });
```

Answer (score 0):

like this ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-geomjb

```
work.pipe(
    concatMap(({ id, dialogRef }) => forkJoin({ id: of(id), dialogRef })),
    exhaustMap(({ id, dialogRef }) => http.get({ id }).pipe(tap(() => dialogRef.close())))
).subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `concat` like this:

```js
work.pipe(
  exhaustMap(({id, dialogRef}) => concat(http.get(id), dialogRef.close()))
).subscribe()
```

If you want to run `dialogRef.close` after `http.get`, just add `defer` for it:

```js
work.pipe(
  exhaustMap(({id, dialogRef}) => concat(
    http.get(id),
    defer(() => dialogRef.close())
  ))
).subscribe()
```